# How does Postgres calculate the current_timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, amazon-aurora

I'm running the following query on the same Postgres database (the database is actually an AWS Aurora Postgres database)

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

in 2 different contexts. When I run it within a database tool running on my laptop I get back

```
2021-05-21 18:12:13.398132
```

but, when I run the exact same query in a server side page on a website running on AWS, I get back

```
2021-05-21 11:12:40.508504
```

These are both being run against the same Postgres database.

The result in my database tool running on my laptop is GMT, the the result when running on the server is Pacific timezone.

I would have expected Postgres to use the timezone of the server (AWS Aurora) that it is running on. Instead it appears to be picking up the timezone based on the web server or my laptop? Though that doesn't make much sense since my laptop is using Pacific time (where I am located).

How does Postgres calculate the current_timestamp?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

it probably has to do with the application itself.
When apps connect to postgres, they can SET the timezone at session level.
Something like this:

```
SET TIMEZONE='GMT';
```

Try checking the timezone of your session with both tools using:

```
SHOW TIMEZONE
```

Later, this timezone is used with the "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" types to show the appropriate date/time.